# Run a request every 3 hours

Tags: php, cron, jobs

I have an API I need to use to send info to it but this API requires me to get an access token every three hours. My question is not about the API itself but about the way I have to do this. I know I need to use cron jobs to do it. But is this the only way to do it, or can I make php scheduale itself to do it? If not, then can I make the cron job "make a request" rather than "running a script"?
What I had in mind is that I would make a php file that would trigger my system to get the new token(all the token request data and function will be held inside my system rather than the cronjob file), rather than a file setting outside my project and making changes to it from the outside. Is this a good idea to do it, or should I just make the cronjob file get the token for me?
I hope I made my point correctly.

Answer (score 0):

first of all cronjob does not do anything itself like you said "make a request". it is exactly do "running a script". now for you answer there are ways you can do this but best way for this kind of job is cron. cause its working under kernel and its completely reliable and stable. 
second, what do you mean by "held inside my system rather than the cronjob file"?
if you mean you store your access token in you code and now you have to store it in a file because cron runs a script and that script save a token somewhere and its not safe, so simply do this:
create script that write file just 0 or 1. every 3 hours this script runs by cron and change the 0 to 1. you code always check this file, if the value is 1 so the token has been expired and you generate new token before making new api call and at the end you change that file to 0 again. it just a simple way. 
but be aware its not best practice and if you can JUST IMPLEMENT REFRESH TOKEN METHOD on the other side.

Comment: I am totally new to this so thank you very much. It is clear now to me so I know now what to do. Thank you very much sir!!

Answer (score 0):

If the script that you want to run is web-based, you could consider using a 3rd-party service, such as [crono](https://www.crono.com/), to programmatically set up your jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can record the token created on a file everytime the cron job runs you can verify the time it have been existing and your code could decide on asking for a new token if it almost reaches its expiration which is 3hrs. But it would be ideal if you do it 15mins before expiration cause there is a difference to when you get the token and the time the token was finally generated by the 3rd party system although the difference is possibly not that huge but a lot of things could happen during the transmission so the time of generation and ETA is not always the same. :)